# optimization with multiple parameters and differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

There might be some relevant questions and answers, but I couldn't complete my code by myself just by reading them. Sorry that I am very new to Mathematica and my question could be a bit rough and not well-organized.

I am trying to find the parameter sets of my differential equations that satisfy some conditions I want to impose.

For a much simpler example, say these are my equations of interest,

```
s = NDSolve[{a y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}];
ss = NDSolve[{b y''[x] + c Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0,10}];
```

and I want to find the sets (a,b,c) that satisfy

```
y[6]/.s==y[6]/.ss
```

For instance,

```
a = -1;
b = 1.4882301;
c = 3;
```

this set roughly satisfies the condition but is presumably not the only solution. So what I want to do is, if I simply fix c=3, by tracking a and b, I will be able to plot a-b that the condition is satisfied. Likewise, I want to find all the sets (maybe sequences of sets) under certain conditions for the parameters (fixed a, fixed b,...).

It may take a huge amount of time, but basically, I can do this with my hand by finding one solution and varying the parameters infinitesimally. The point is, I want this to be done as automatically as possible. It might require some steps to be there, but my final aim is, put c=3 and press enter are all that I need to do once the code is made.

I feel like in some way I should use Module (and maybe FindRoot?), but not sure about how to. Can anyone give me some help on how to achieve this? Again, I am very poor at this software yet and even just giving me the right direction will be appreciated.

Thank you

---

Thanks to @BobHanlon I could catch somehow how to approach this problem. However, if I apply this method to a more complicated version, it doesn't work.
Here are the actual functions that I want to work on

```
eqold[\[CapitalSigma]_] = {Z'[s] == -Sin[\[Psi][s]], \[Psi]''[
    s] == -\[Psi]'[s]/X[s] Cos[\[Psi][s]] + 
    Cos[\[Psi][s]] Sin[\[Psi][s]]/X[s]^2 + \[Gamma][s]/
      X[s] Sin[\[Psi][s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[\[Psi][s]], \[Gamma]'[
    s] == (\[Psi]'[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[\[Psi][s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + 
    P X[s] Sin[\[Psi][s]] + \[CapitalSigma], X'[s] == Cos[\[Psi][s]]};
help[eq_] := (Subtract @@ eq // Together // Numerator) == 0
C0 = 0; s1 = 2 \[Pi];
nobsoln = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{1, 4}]], 
   help /@ eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{2, 3}]], \[Psi][0] == 
    0, \[Psi]'[0] == a, X[0] == 0, \[Gamma][0] == 0, 
   Z[0] == 0}, {X, \[Psi], Z, \[Gamma]}, {s, 0, s1}, {a, 
   P, \[CapitalSigma]0}, SolveDelayed -> True]; sobsoln = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{1, 4}]], 
   help /@ eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{2, 3}]], \[Psi][
     s1] == \[Pi], \[Psi]'[s1] == a, X[s1] == 0, \[Gamma][s1] == 0, 
   Z[s1] == 0}, {X, \[Psi], Z, \[Gamma]}, {s, 0, s1}, {a, 
   P, \[CapitalSigma]0}, SolveDelayed -> True];
```

(Sorry for this strange display of the greek letters, I simply copied and pasted the code and am not sure how to fix this).

The matching conditions I want to impose are

```
X[3] /. nobsoln == X[3] /. sobsoln
\[Psi][3] /. nobsoln == \[Psi][3] /. sobsoln
```

Or actually, I want nobsoln and sobsoln to be identical except for s=0 and s=s1, where they are singular.

I know that

```
P = 1.37889;
\[CapitalSigma]0 = -1.1 P^(2/3);
a = 0.0895105;
```

is one of the solutions.

Then I defined the "data" like you did (this was typically aimed to check the above solution)

```
data = Table[{\[CapitalSigma]0 /. 
      FindRoot[(X[a, 1.37889, \[CapitalSigma]0][3] /. 
          nobsoln) == (X[a, 1.37889, \[CapitalSigma]0][3] /. 
          sobsoln), {\[CapitalSigma]0, -1.36}], a}, {a, 
     Range[0.07, 0.09, 10^(-4)]}] // Quiet;
```

The issue pops up here. If I run this, the "running" continues for some seconds and suddenly just stops and resets things like I "quit kernel". This kind of error happened occasionally for some other codes, but they were resolved just by rerunning, but this one never works however I try.

Can someone figure out why this happens either in general or typically for this code? and give me some useful advice on how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is singular in a case of actual systems with initial points  `X[0] == 0` and `X[s1] == 0` for  `nobsoln` and  `sobsoln` consequently. This singularity crashes kernel without message.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for pointing out the origin of this issue. Can you also give me some advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem as you want here "I want nobsoln and sobsoln to be identical except for s=0 and s=s1, where they are singular". Then what do you mean here `X[3] /. nobsoln == X[3] /. sobsoln; \[Psi][3] /. nobsoln == \[Psi][3] /. sobsoln`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Actually, s=3 is what I picked arbitrarily. Basically, for the desired parameter sets, nobsoln and sobsoln are identical except for s=0 and s=s1. So I am checking if they are equal by examining an arbitrary point of s.

Comment: This code may help a bit in understanding what I mean by
`p = 1.37889;
\[Sigma]0 = -1.1 p^(2/3);
C0 = 0;
aa = -0.08846200000000001 p/\[Sigma]0; s1 = 2 \[Pi];
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[X[aa, p, \[Sigma]0][s] /. nobsoln], {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[Evaluate[\[Psi][aa, p, \[Sigma]0][s] /. nobsoln], {s, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[Evaluate[X[aa, p, \[Sigma]0][s] /. sobsoln], {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}],
 Plot[Evaluate[\[Psi][aa, p, \[Sigma]0][s] /. sobsoln], {s, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], PlotRange -> Full]`

Comment: If you slightly change any parameter, they are not identical anymore. As a way of examining their correspondence, I am looking at an arbitrary point of s.

Comment: How we know that solutions are identical on $0<s<s1$? Plotting it is not right method. We need to propose some measure to compute parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

eqns1 = {a y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
```

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[eqns1, y, {x, 0, 10}, {a}];

plt1 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[
     Tooltip[y[a][x] /. s, a],
     {a, {-2, -1, 1, 2}}],
   {x, 0, 10},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{-2, -1, 1, 2},
     LegendLabel -> Style[a, 12, Bold]]];
```

Similarly,

```
eqns2[b_, c_] = {b y''[x] + c Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};

ss = ParametricNDSolve[eqns2[b, c], y, {x, 0, 10}, {b, c}];

With[{c = 3},
  plt2 = Plot[
    Evaluate@
     Table[
      Tooltip[y[b, c][x] /. ss, b],
      {b, {-2, -1, 1, 2}}],
    {x, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> Dashed,
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{-2, -1, 1, 2},
      LegendLabel -> Style[b, 12, Bold]]]];
```

Combining the plots,

```
Show[plt1, plt2, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

To find the intersections for a fixed value of `c` (e.g., `c == 3`) use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html). Note that good initial estimates for a parameter must be given to `FindRoot`

```
data =
  Table[
    Table[
     {a, b /. FindRoot[(y[a][6] /. s) == (y[b, 3][6] /. ss), {b, est}]},
     {a, Range[-2, 2, 0.1] /. {0. -> Nothing}}],
    {est, 0.1, 2, 0.1}] // Quiet;
```

Plotting the data,

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {a, b})]
```

[image]

For `a == -1` the **found** values (i.e., may not be all-inclusive) of `b` are

```
Last /@ (
  Mean /@
   GatherBy[
    Cases[data, {-1., _}, Infinity],
    Round[#[[2]], 0.000001] &])

(* {0.108524, 0.232989, 0.314367, 0.814686, 1.48823} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think this method makes sense. I really appreciate it.
However, if I try to apply the same strategy to my actual functions, it keeps failing to run the "data" step. It is on "running" for a while (like some seconds) and then it just stops and reset things like I quit kernel.
I've experienced this kind of error? occasionally, but it was resolved just by rerunning, but this one never works.
Can you also figure this out why?

Comment: There is not enough info for me to make a recommendation.

Comment: I added my actual functions in the main post. If you can take a look at it. Thank you much anyway.